# ASP.NET WebMatrix SQL Database FETCH NEXT ROWS by each time Button click?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, razor, webmatrix

I'm a beginner and This is the first time I'm working with Database. I'm trying to FETCH NEXT ROWS from SQL Database table by each time a Button click. I create a button to post and trying to increase the number of rows by 3 each time but it's not WORKING?

As you can see the OFFSET value is always 0 and default number of ROWS is 3 and when somebody click the button then I want to increase 3 rows each time. If first time somebody click the button then I want the number of rows to increase from 3 to 6, second time 6 to 9 and So on...

I'm trying to accomplish this with ASP.NET Razor Loops or similar way by changing and updating the Value of FETCH NEXT ROWS with a Submit Button each time.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you & Here is my code:

**.cshtml**

```
@{
    var i += 3;
    var value = i + Request["submit"];
    var db = Database.Open("WebSite");
    var selectQueryString = "SELECT * FROM WebSite ORDER BY NAME OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT ('3 + value.AsInt()') ROWS ONLY";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            @foreach(var row in db.Query(selectQueryString))
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@row.NAME</td>
                    <td><img alt="#" src="@row.URL"></td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <button type="submit" name="submit">Load More</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I understand that you are a beginner but could you give us a bit more info around what kind of web app you are trying to create.  Razor is a view engine.  The only code in your views should be display logic.  you should do your database access code in a controller.  You can then use thing like Html.BeginForm http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505244(v=vs.118).aspx to render your form and make it call actions on your controller.

Comment: @BenRobinson I'm trying to load more ITEMS from the database and I can't use paging because paging jump to next set of results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some mistakes in your code.

I have applied your request to the Northwind sample database in the following

```
@{
    var rowsNumb = 3;
    var db = Database.Open("Northwind");

    if (IsPost){
        rowsNumb = Request["lastRec"].AsInt() + 3;
    }

    var maxRecs = db.QueryValue("SELECT COUNT([Product Id]) FROM Products");
    var sql = @"SELECT * FROM Products ORDER BY [Product Id] 
                OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT @0 ROWS  ONLY";
    rowsNumb = (rowsNumb > maxRecs ? maxRecs : rowsNumb);
    var result = db.Query(sql, rowsNumb);
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            @foreach(var row in result){
                <tr>
                    <td>@row["Product Name"]</td>
                    <td>@row["English Name"]</td>
                    <td>@row["Unit Price"]</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="lastRec" value="@rowsNumb" />
            <button type="submit">Load More</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have used an hidden field to store the rows number displayed the last time and every time test if the number of rows to display is greater of the total rows number.